# Getting UDP traffic statistic between particular hosts on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, statistics, udp

I need to gather some network statistic to test my server application. I've tried many linux tools, but nothing I've found suits my needs.

Basically I want to gather some UDP statistics (bytes/time_interval, packets/time_interval, packets_loss), but regarding only two particular hosts - for example I want to get UDP statistic from traffic going from IP_A:PORT_A to IP_B:PORT_B.

Tools like tcpdump/wireshark can easily dump such traffic but I have problems with getting statistics like temporary speed (too see throughput peeks), and linux system statistics gives me number for all traffic.

It would be better to get text output so it will be possible to parse it.

Anyone has any idea how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance
Harnen

Comment: wireshark have an I/O graph, is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial for the libpcap library:

- http://www.systhread.net/texts/200805lpcap1.php

To determine packets lost, your program will probably want to work on a pair of logs, and make sure UDP messages on the source are found on the destination. A good method for doing this is to maintain a window of packets equal to the amount of time your timeout is set to, load all the packets into the window, sort them, then search for all the packets in the desired time frame, marking them as found as you go. Once you've exhausted a minute, remove half of that minute from the buffer, and load the next thirty seconds and re-sort.

If you have lots (millions? probably should profile it) of packets, it may be *faster* to use what's called a [Counting Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Counting_filters), so you can determine if your packet is "probably" in there very quickly.

If you weren't looking for programming advice, take your question to serverfault.